# How to call a same variable in class by two difference class in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Swift.
I save some variable and function in `CouchBase.swift` , and there has two swift will call the function and variable in `CouchBase.swift`.

The `ViewController.swift` set the **uuid** in `CouchBase.swift` and change to the `DeviceInfo.swift`. But when I call `getuuid` in the `DeviceInfo.swift` , it return the empty value;

In `CouchBase.swift`

```
class Couchbase {

    ar userPassword = "";
    var userUUID = "";

func setuuid(uuid: String){

        self.userUUID = uuid
    }
func getUserUUID() -> NSString{
        return userUUID;
    }
}
```

In `ViewController.swift`

```
var cbase = Couchbase()

cbase.setuuid("aaa")
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("DeviceInfo", sender: self)  //change to DeviceInfo.swift
```

In `DeviceInfo.swift`

```
import Foundation
class Deviceinfo: ViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {      
    println("cbase.getUserUUID() = \(cbase.getUserUUID())")
    }
}
```

**The log show `cbase.getUserUUID() =` , How to use the same variable in two different swift class ?**

Why the value is empty when I call `cbase.getUserUUID()` in `DeviceInfo.swift` ?

Comment: How are you getting the cbase in the DeviceInfo.swift file?

Comment: Why the get/set methods? userUUID is already a public property.

Comment: @Naughty_Ottsel I just direct use it via `cbase.getUserUUID()`.

Comment: @ThomasKilian So...how do I call userUUID in DeviceInfo.swift ?

Comment: Simply `println("cbase.userUUID = \(cbase.userUUID)")` though I don't see where you declared `cbase` relative to DeviceInfo.

Comment: N.B.: You should probably leave planet Java for a while and read Apple's eBook about Swift.

Comment: @ThomasKilian I have try before I ask the question , it is the same. After I try the Answer. The cbase in DeviceInfo.swift already has property same as ViewController class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `cbase` property of ViewController class to `Deviceinfo` class.

For that you can use the `prepareForSegue` method, Implement the following method in First view controller class:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!)
{
    let destinationVC   = segue.destinationViewController as Deviceinfo
    destinationVC.cbase = self.cbase
}
```

**Note:** Assuming that `cbase` is a public property in the `Deviceinfo` class also.